# Prevent reset of currentTime when video loads?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to be able to reload the video into the HTML5 video without having to reset the currentTime when it is loaded. The way I am currently doing it is the following:

```
<button onclick="getCurTime()" type="button">Get current time position</button>
<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 5 seconds</button><br> 
<div style="width:800px; height:445px;">
<video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%" controls="controls">
 <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function setCurTime() { 
    vid.currentTime=100;
} 
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
    $('#myVideo').videocontrols( 
    { 
        preview: 
        { 
            sprites: ['big_bunny_108p_preview.jpg'], 
            step: 10, 
            width: 200 
        }, 
        theme: 
        { 
            progressbar: 'blue', 
            range: 'pink', 
            volume: 'pink' 
        } 
    }); 
    vid.play();
}); 
setInterval(function(){ 
    if(vid.currentTime > vid.duration-1)
    {
    myVideo.src = "http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4";
myVideo.load();
myVideo.play();
vid.currentTime = vid.duration-60*5
}
 }, 1);
</script> 
</div>
```

How would I go about doing this? Is there even a way to just update the data in the video player without having to reload the video? I want to be able to do this so if someone makes a modification to the video, it will just update the data in the video player so the user doesn't have to reload the whole video again.

Comment: not 100% sure what you're trying to do... are you wanting to reload (why) or replace the current video, but keep the currentTime marker the same? The way to do that would be track the current time when the request to change is made and then set it when the new video loads

Comment: Yes, but whenever I try to do that(when it reloads), the video resets and changing the currentTime doesn't work.

Comment: You won't be able to set the time until after the metadataloaded event has fired

Comment: Then how would I go about fixing my code so that the currentTime is set when the video is ready to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per discussion in comment thread above, I'm still not 100% sure why you're reloading the same video so I may be missing some context, but the following code will let you change the video source but preserve the current time. It does assume `jQuery` for the event handler (though you can easily use the regular javascript event handler on the same event to do the same thing)

```
<video id="v" width="320" height="240" controls="controls" mute>
<source src="Video.mp4" />
</video>
<button onclick="reload()">Reload</button>

<script>
function reload() {
    vid=document.getElementById("v")
    // record the current time for the video that is playing
    curTime = vid.currentTime
    // set the source for the replacement video...
    vid.src = "http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4";
    // ... and load it
    vid.load();
    // add event handler for "canplay" to set the time, and then start the video
    $("#v").on("canplay",function() {
        vid.currentTime = curTime
        vid.play();
        // remove the event to stop it triggering multiple times
        $("#v").off("canplay")
    })
}
</script>
```